# How to Modify a Global Date Variable

Tags: global-variables, date-format, entry-date

Is it possible to modify a date variable (entry_date in this case) so that you have entry_date plus one year (or any other amount of time)?

For example, if entry_date was 6/4/14 2:59 PM, could I add one year to that date and end up with 6/4/15 2:59 PM, and would I still be able to use that variable in a conditional statement?

EDIT: Essentially what I want is something like this:

```
{if (entry_date + one_year) > current_time}
    <p>New Product</p>
{/if}
```

SECOND EDIT:

Robson, I tried the code that you added (both the regular and inverted logic) and I'm unfortunately STILL ending up with the same error. However, I continued to play around with the code and found that this does not throw an error:

```
{if {current_time format="%Y%m%d%H%i"} == {entry_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"}}
    less than an year
{if:else}
    more than an year
{/if}
```

But this does throw the same error:

```
{if {current_time format="%Y%m%d%H%i"} - {entry_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"} == 1}
    less than an year
{if:else}
    more than an year
{/if}
```

Do I need to change the comparative number to something more specific? Are we comparing two variables that we can't compare? Or am I just missing some bracket again? I feel like it's almost there...

Comment: Please, give me a little more detail on the conditional you need, so I can try to help you.

Comment: I made an edit above you so could see the code more easily.

Comment: Are you using which version of EECMS?

Comment: I'm using ExpressionEngine v2.8.1

Comment: Mathematical operators works just on 2.9+.

Comment: Ahh, is there no other option then? You mentioned that it can be done with an add-on?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried something like this, but maybe it could work.

You can't add a year to a date without an add-on., but there are [mathematical operators](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#mathematic-operators) on the conditionals.

[Format the date](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html) like a number using all data required by the precision you need plus one year following the same format: YYYYMMDDHHMM.

```
{if {entry_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"} + 100000000 > {current_time format="%Y%m%d%H%i"} }
    less than an year
{if:else}
    more than an year
{/if}
```

Maybe it's better to invert the logic to make the code easier to understand:

```
{if {current_time format="%Y%m%d%H%i"} - {entry_date format="%Y%m%d%H%i"} < 100000000  }
    less than an year
{if:else}
    more than an year
{/if}
```

---

### Using an add-on

If you can't update to EECMS 2.9 you can code your own add-on for this using strtotime() php function, like [Low Nice Date](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date) does.

```
{exp:low_nice_date date="{entry_date format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i + 1 Year'}" format="%Y%m%d%H%i"}
```

But the code will become far more complex and harder to maintain.

Comment: I tried this code, but replaced the XXX with current_time, added a close bracket, and closed the conditional statement, but I ended up with this error -- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FALSE' (T_STRING) in /home/constbookbni/domains/constructionbook.bnibooks.com/public_html/ee/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(689) : eval()'d code on line 33

Comment: Did you notice my code has an extra `)`? I'm sorry about it!

Comment: I just tried the modified code in your post and I'm still throwing the same error.

Comment: I wrote the name of the variable wrong again. I'm really, really sorry! I tested the code exactly how it is now and it works fine.

Comment: It almost works...I edited my original post for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Please, @BMack, try to leave just this conditional inside the `exp:channel:entries` loop to check if it's the problem.